# How to convert *redis.SliceCmd to []string in golang?

Tags: go, redis

I use `github.com/go-redis/redis/v8` , and I want to get the value in redis :

```golang
userProfile := util.RedisClusterClient.HMGet(redisCtx, redisUserProfileHashkey, userIdSlice...)
```

But the `HMGet` return a `*redis.SliceCmd` , not a `[]string` . Why does the module design this ? How can I get a `[]string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the various *Cmd return values have a `cmd.Result()` method for accessing the result, as well as an `cmd.Err()` method for testing for success.

See https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8#SliceCmd

Comment: But why does `HMGet` `cmd.Result()` return `[]interface{}`, while `HGet` and `HGetAll` `cmd.Result()` both return `string` and `map[string]string`, respectively? Should `HMGet` also return `map[string]string`?

Comment: @Marko Ask a question if you have a question, rather than posting unrelated comments to random answers.